# Get path of corresponding controller action view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Normally rails would automatically render the file corresponding to the controller and action. For example an action `index` in `TestController` could render the file `app/views/test/index.html.erb`. **Is there a dynamic way where I can get the path of the corresponding action view file?** For example, if I have `test#something` I want to get `app/views/test/something.html.erb`.

Comment: Do you mean get view file like `app/views/test/something/something.html.erb`? Please specify your question.

Comment: I am still confused. Do you mean you want to render this file or do you need a method to return the directory as string?

Comment: Directory as a string

Comment: Can you give a specific example like where do you want to get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible. Check out [LookupContext](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths.html) and [`view_renderer`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/AbstractController/Rendering/view_renderer).

Within controller's action:

```
lookup_context.find_template("#{controller_path}/#{action_name}").identifier
```

Within view:

```
@view_renderer.lookup_context.find_template(@virtual_path).identifier
```

Comment: accepted! just got the chance to test it just now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now, how to find the path of a partial?