# How to find all the view paths for a given action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following is defined in app/controllers/support_controller.rb and I do not have a template support/test in the views folder.

```
class SupportController < ActionController::Base
  def test
  end
end
```

As expected, Rails throws the following exception which includes a list of directories where it searched for the template:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /test
Missing template support/test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/slowmo/Desktop/Apps/courier/app/views"
  * "/Users/slowmo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre1/app/views"
  * "/Users/slowmo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/kaminari-0.17.0/app/views"
  * "/Users/slowmo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/devise_cas_authenticatable-1.10.4/app/views"
  * "/Users/slowmo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views"
```

I would like to know if there is a method which returns the list of directories shown above for that action? I know `prepend_view_path` allows me to add to that list but I can't find any documentation on how I can read from that path list?

Comment: is not rails routes pipe grep name of the action?

Comment: No sorry, I am trying to find a method which returns the view paths for the action (the directories where rails will look for the view template)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34128505/10895713

Comment: Perhaps look at [ActionView::PathSet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/path_set.rb) and [ActionView::ViewPaths](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb)? You *may* be able to do `all_view_paths` (ActionView::ViewPaths line 51) and then grep for what you're looking for.

Comment: You could use something like `self.view_paths` in your controller (as @jvillian's comment suggests). However, Rails will look for the pattern (ie `@pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}`). So, if you don't have the template in the `app/views/support` directory, there is nothing to lookup and you will have to explicitly render something.